# Optimizing LINQ Query to avoid multiple enumerations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, ienumerable

I have written a code like this in my .NET project:

```
var v = ctx.Items
        .Where(x => x.userid== user.userid)
        .Select(e => new MyViewModel
        {
          Title = e.Title,
          CurrentPrice = e.CurrenctPrice.Value,
          ItemID = e.ItemID.ToString(),
          Sales = e.Transactions.Where(p => p.TransactionDate >= intoPast && p.TransactionDate <= endDate).Sum(x => x.QuantityPurchased)
         })
         .Where(x => x.Sales > 0 && ((filterWord == "") || (filterWord != "" && x.Title.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower()))));
```

where "ctx" is my object context variable...

And this is the ViewModelClass that I use:

```
  public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Sales { get; set; }
        public string ItemID { get; set; }
        public double CurrentPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

The thing that most bugs me here is the sales property... As you can see i set its value in select statement. This way all my data gets  enumerated every time...

What I was thinking here is to create a method called "getsales()"... And then to just simply call the GetSales method in my where statement like this:

```
.Where(x=>X.GetSales(/*neccesary parameters here*/)...)
```

In order to avoid having multiple enumerations...

But I'm not really sure how to do it...

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Hey @Nkosi why did you delete the reply , I was just gonna read it xD

Comment: Can you just move the `filter` part of the query up to the initial `.Where` clause? Also, you don't need the `filterWord != ""` part, because for that section of code to execute, `filterWord == ""` must have already evaluated to `false`

Comment: @RufusL You mean like this:           
                             .Where(x => x.Sales > 0 && ((filterWord == "") || (x.Title.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower())))); ?

P.S. I didn't get that first part, could you reply in a form of answer so that I can see what you ment ?

Comment: @RufusL okay I got it now, just move the filterWord into first where statement... Is there any way to fox the thingy for the Sales property?

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Comment: I think that what @RufusL was saying is that if you move the second Where clause into the first one, the problem you are asking about is solved as well.  I.e., you'll then only be retrieving the Sales data for the items that meet the filter criteria instead of getting it for everything and then filtering that set down after the fact.

Comment: Yeah but if i move the where clause to first part of  query, wouldnt i be then operating with a completely different data set, in this case my items class/table, whereas when the >0 sales is down below then im operating on sales that are from transactions table (which are a bit more specific)? And im trying to operate on sales property from transactions table. If i moved everything to first clause then id be filtering items table, which is not what i want 

Comment: What makes you think this is enumerating multiple times? The .Sum() at the end should mean that doesn't happen. What makes you think it is happening?

Comment: how will .GetSales() minimize the iterations if it's within the linq query and does the same thing?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var v = ctx.Items
    .Where(x =>
        x.userid == user.userid &&
        (filterWord == "" || x.Title.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower())))
    .Select(e => new MyViewModel
    {
        Title = e.Title,
        CurrentPrice = e.CurrentPrice.Value,
        ItemID = e.ItemID.ToString(),
        Sales = e.Transactions
            .Where(p => 
                p.TransactionDate >= intoPast && 
                p.TransactionDate <= endDate)
            .Sum(x => x.QuantityPurchased)
    })
    .Where(x => x.Sales > 0);
```

Comment: Hey Rufus, thanks for the reply, it says here in the modified where statement the following: information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ah, true! In that case, `Contains` is the way to go. Updated the answer